# AWS NodeJS Serverless - Zip Error When Deploying Project

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, serverless

I am deploying a serverless nodeJS project in AWS that has implemented only a single lambda function that should returns the items in a dynamoDB table.
However, when I run the command:

```
sls deploy -v
```

I got the following error:

[image]

My project is at this linke here:
[enter link description here](https://github.com/MKortmann/CloudDeveloper-Project04)

The problem is at the dev branch.

Do someone knows what it can be?
**Thank you very much in advance!**

Cheers,

Marcelo

Comment: I have tried to deploy your app to my AWS and it is deployed successfully!

Comment: Do you think it can be my serverless or even node version? Node version: v14.16.0 Serverless Framework Core: 2.37.0 (local)
Plugin: 4.5.3
SDK: 4.2.2
Components: 3.9.0

Comment: In my local machine I have `Node: v14.16.0`,  `Serverless Framework Core: 2.4.0`, `Plugin: 4.0.4`, `SDK: 2.3.2`, `Components: 3.2.1`.

Answer (score 1):

I've just created a boilerplate today and got the same error.

I've managed to solve it specifying the **serverless-webpack's version to 5.3.5**.

Follow these steps:

1. Delete node_modules and package-lock.json `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json`
2. Change serverless-webpack version from `"serverless-webpack": "^5.3.5"` to `"serverless-webpack": "5.3.5"` **without the ^ or ~ in front of the version**
3. Install the dependencies with `npm install` command
4. Deploy your app with `sls deploy --verbose`